# Error Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Tags: c#, json

I have a class like this

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Award> award { get; set; }
}
public class Award
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}
```

### Json award

```
"[{\"name\":\"Student of the month\",\"year\":\"2017-01-01\"},
{\"name\":\"National Hero\",\"year\":\"2017-01-01\"}]"
```

I deserialize like this

```
var awardList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(award)
foreach (var item in awardList.award)
{
    Profile.Awards.Add(item);
}
```

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type. What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided JSON you are deserializing to the wrong type. The provided JSON is just a collection of awards at the root.

Deserialize like...

```
var awardList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Award[]>(award);
foreach (var item in awardList) {
    Profile.Awards.Add(item);
}
```

The JSON would have to look like below to match the original code provided

```
{ 
    "award": [
        {"name":"Student of the month","year":"2017-01-01"},
        {"name":"National Hero","year":"2017-01-01"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json award string that you mentioned is not matching with RootObject class structure.

Serialized String for RootObject should be like this

```
{"award":[{"name":"Student of the month","year":"2017"},{"name":"National Hero",
```

"year":"2017"}]}